# Can I create REST API with XML as response?

Tags: node.js, xml, rest

Can I create REST API with XML as response? I know how to create and return JSON as response but not sure about XML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js: how to consume SOAP XML web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655252/node-js-how-to-consume-soap-xml-web-service)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah; you always could create a REST API with XML as response.
[How can I respond in XML using ExpressJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398279/how-can-i-respond-in-xml-using-expressjs)

[How to response data as xml in node.js instead of json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153193/how-to-response-data-as-xml-in-node-js-instead-of-json)

[Expressjs response as JSON and Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399572/expressjs-response-as-json-and-xml)

Also when asking a question first go through stack overflow to check if same question asked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also tell, we can create and consume SOAP services in node? If yes, then is it a good choice and how much effort will it take?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655252/node-js-how-to-consume-soap-xml-web-service